# Equal Flow to differently spaced water recepticles

Tags: liquid, water-pressure

I'm Designing a self watering planter, and I want to split the water from a main resevoir at the top to 5 smaller tanks below, but they are at differing elevations and distances from the resevoir. What is the best way to split the water evenly?

For Now my idea is to use aquarium tubing and to have the ones higher up to be smaller tubes/more tapered to allow for less flow, but not sure how to do the math to get it to be exact.
[image]

[image]

Heres the rough sizing of it all: [image]

Comment: use drip irrigation nozzles ... some are adjustable... some are calibrated to pass a specific amount of water per hour

Comment: Thats a really good idea, thanks